# ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this) return SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD on the device not supported but installed google play service for arcore

Tags: android, arcgis, arcore

**ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this)** return **SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD** on the device not supported but installed google play service for arcore
**MyDevice：**Xiaomi 10s (not on the supported device list) Honer V20 (on the supported  list)
(1) delete the ArCore retrun UNKNOWN_ERROR on both,
(2) install ArCore retrun SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD on  Xiaomi 10s,this should return UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE_NOT_CAPABLE or UNKNOWN_ERROR . retrun SUPPORTED_INSTALLED on Honer V20 this is currect.

**Q1:is this a bug or my code hava peoblem?**

**Q2:is only the devices on the list can use ArCore or availebe on the devices  hardware support Arcore ?**

**Q3:what is the requrement of hardware? Xiaomi 10 is supported but Xiaomi  10s is not?**

there is my code

```
ArCoreApk.Availability availability = ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this);
            switch (availability) {
                case UNKNOWN_CHECKING:
                    new Handler().postDelayed(this::maybeOpenARNavigateActivity, 200);
                    break;
                case SUPPORTED_INSTALLED:
                    mapGISFrame.startActivity(new Intent(this, ARNavigateActivity.class));
                    break;
                case SUPPORTED_NOT_INSTALLED: log(); break;
                case SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD:log(); break;
                case UNKNOWN_ERROR:log(); break;
                case UNKNOWN_TIMED_OUT:log(); break;
                case UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE_NOT_CAPABLE:log(); break;
                default:log(); break;
     }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.